# String Enum in C# for creating a JSON

Tags: c#, json

I have a [Blazor component](https://github.com/erossini/BlazorChartjs) for creating graphs with ChartJs. Based on the models, C# creates a Json for the Chart configuration. Some configurations have defined values that I can use: for example, the `PointStyle` accepts only few values such as *circle* and *cross*.

For this reason, I want to have the constraint to select only the accepted values for this configuration. Then, in my project I created a class `PointStyle` to have a sort of enum with string.

```
public class PointStyle
{
    private PointStyle(string value) { Value = value; }

    public string Value { get; private set; }

    public static PointStyle Circle { get { return new PointStyle("circle"); } }
    public static PointStyle Cross { get { return new PointStyle("cross"); } }
}
```

To obtain the correct Json configuration, in the main model I created 2 properties: `PointStyle` and `PointStyleString`.

```
[JsonIgnore]
public PointStyle? PointStyle { 
    get => _pointStyle; 
    set
    {
        _pointStyle = value;
        PointStyleString = _pointStyle.Value;
    }
}
private PointStyle? _pointStyle;

[JsonPropertyName("pointStyle")]
[JsonIgnore(Condition = JsonIgnoreCondition.WhenWritingDefault)]
public string? PointStyleString { get; set; }
```

`PointStyle` accepts only the values in the defined list but this is ignored from the Json converter. For example, I can configure this like

```
PointStyle = PointStyle.Cross
```

Then, the public variable `PointStyleString` contains the string I have to serialize in the Json and this is updated when the `PointStyle` sets a new value.

Now, I have to read the property `Value` from the class `PointStyle` that contains the string I have to pass to the configuration. For this reason, I have a private variable _*pointStyle* that saves the value for `PointStyle`; so, when a new value is set, I also set the `PointStyleString`.

When the configuration is ready, I pass through `JSRuntime` the configuration like

```
await JSRuntime.InvokeVoidAsync("setup", Config.CanvasId, dotnet_ref, Config);
```

I don't know exactly how the `Config` is translated to the Json but the resulted Json is correct for the graph.

Everything I described above is working but it seems to me quite complicated for just setting a value. Do you think I can simplify this code?

Comment: I am pretty sure you could use an actual enum ... give me a minute.

Comment: And here you go: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json/customize-properties?pivots=dotnet-6-0#enums-as-strings